# Redirect client to specific URL openvpn?

Tags: configuration, openvpn, redirection

Soon I'm going to have to change my VPN server's IP address. This will mean that current client configuration files will no longer work with the new server. I was wondering if it's somehow possible to notify the client of such a change. The main idea I was thinking of was to redirect them to a webpage with this information on a web browser to notify them of such a change. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use DNS? Then IP change will be easy and no config file change needed.

Comment: @ESYSCODER The issue is that the clients are connecting directly to the numerical IP for the server so I don't think I can use DNS.